# Fetching multiple records while sampling epoch timestamp feild from MySQL table?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I have a table with feilds like

```
TimeStamp     |  Feild1      | Feild 2
--------------------------------------
1902909002    |  xyddtz      | 233447
1902909003    |  xytzff      | 233442
1902909005    |  xytzdd      | 233443
1902909007    |  xytzdd      | 233443
1902909009    |  xytsqz      | 233436
```

Now i want to query it and fetch records like between 1902909002 and 1902909007 which will be easily done with :

```
Select * from table where timestamp > 1902909001 AND timestamp < 1902909008
```

but two more things i want to do is :

1. maybe that particular time stamp is not there so i have to find nearest value
2. like if there are 200 records in that range but i want to fetch only 20 so i want to skip every 19 records in a row and fetch 20th, 40th etc records.
3. i will be having date in datetime format. i know i can convert it before querying but if there is some option in query itself then it willbe better.

Comment: do not store timestamps as int just use `TIMESTAMP` type

Comment: ya sure but what about query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (it is crucial for both queries to be exec in the same mysql session):

```
SET @c:=0;
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        * ,
        @c:=@c+1  as counter
    FROM 
        table 
    WHERE 
        timestamp > 1902909001 
        AND timestamp < 1902909008
) as tmp
WHERE
    counter % 20 =1;
```

Comment: If the total number of records filtered by datestamp are 20 then all the records should be returned and for this your `where` clause will fail as though having 20 records you are returning only 1 record. I was facing same situation and to solve this I had to go for such a complex query...

Comment: from his question i understood that he wants to fetch every 20th row from that set ... i didn't get that if the range has 20 rows then return all of them

Comment: actually i wanted sample these readings.. i will dynamically decide if there are 2000 readings then i want only 100 odd readings to plot some graph and if want to plot graph for time = 10 sec then i will take all readings.. will there be some error executing this query in this scenerio??? @Stephan

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select * from(
select @rn:=if(@rn < rid, rid, @rn) as rn,  rid, timestamp, feild1, feild2
from 
(select @rn:=@rn+1 as rId, tbl.* 
from tbl
join
(select @rn:=0) tmp
where timestamp between 1902909002 and 1902909024 order by rid desc)a
join
(select @rn:=0)tmp)tmp
where rid%(rn div 6)=0
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88200/19)**

Comment: +1 nicely done :) a little over-complicated and also he said every 20th record not every 6th one

Comment: Indeed even i felt it to be little complicated :P. We can change that according to the user needs